# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch - Google cloud api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, redirect-uri-mismatch

I have just setup a new project and added the following scopes for "Web application".
email, and send mail

[image]

I have also enabled **GMailAPI** from **library**

After this I have created credentials. Then edit > redirect_uri

I am not sure what this uri should be but I have tried almost everything here

1. Gmail error message state "If you are a developer of this app see **error details**"

   the url mentioned here : http:\x.x.x.x:1234\authorize\

   with and without ending slash

P.S: when I type above uri in my browser, I get to a break point in my application

2. my home page url

   http:\localhost\default.aspx
3. my calling page uri

   http:\localhost\member\create.aspx

None of these work and I still get redirect_uri_mismatch Access Blocked error

My code is still running on my local machine and not available in google cloud.

**vb.net code**

```
Dim credential As UserCredential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets With {
    .ClientId = "xxx",
    .ClientSecret = "xxx"
    },
    {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"},
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None)
```

[image]

**Update**

I got to know that AuthorizeAsync is for installed applications and not for web apps, here is my updated code...which is not sending me back a token.

```
Public Function DoOauthAndSendEmail(subject As String, body As String, recipients As String) As Task

    Dim fromEmail As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ContactEmail")

    Dim MailMessage As MailMessage = New MailMessage(fromEmail, recipients, subject, body)
    'Specify whether the body Is HTML
    MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True

    'Convert to MimeMessage
    Dim Message As MimeMessage = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(MailMessage)
    
    
    Dim rawMessage As String = Message.ToString()

    Dim flow As IAuthorizationCodeFlow = New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer With {
.ClientSecrets = New ClientSecrets With {
    .ClientId = "CLIENT_ID",
    .ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
},
    .Scopes = {GmailService.Scope.GmailSend}
    })

    

    Dim token As Responses.TokenResponse = New Responses.TokenResponse() 

    If flow IsNot Nothing And token IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim credential As UserCredential = New UserCredential(flow, "user", token)
        Dim success As Boolean = credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result

        Dim gmail As GmailService = New GmailService(New Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
          .ApplicationName = "APP_NAME",
          .HttpClientInitializer = credential
      })

        gmail.Users.Messages.Send(New Message With {
        .Raw = Base64UrlEncode(rawMessage)
    }, "me").Execute()

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: 1) What is the complete URI that you put into the browser? 2) The redirect URI is the URI for your webserver that receives the callback and process the code by exchanging the code for tokens.

Comment: http://localhost:52585/member/create.aspx which is the originating page

Comment: also added the url mentioned in error above - http://localhost:1234/authorize/

Comment: I am guessing that you did not understand my question. When you perform OAuth, you must direct the web browser to go to a URL with a number of query parameters. Your question does not have those details. I recommend that you first read how Google OAuth is performed using, for example, the CURL CLI. I wrote an article on my website that shows how. That way you will understand the steps.

Comment: Please see my edit. The code you are using is designed for installed application if your seeing that error your using the wrong type of credentials.

Comment: You may want to open a new question relating to your issues with a web application.  This is really not the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the wrong place for the redirect uri's it is found under credentials then edit your web app client

[image]

[Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

## update Installed app

The code you are using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is used for authorizing an installed application.  In this instance you need to make sure that you have created an installed application credentials on google cloud console.

[How to create installed application credetilas.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwqJcyLQSSQ)

You should not be seeing a redirect uri error if you have created the correct credentials type for you to match the code you are using.

Comment: hey I have done it under credentials..(see second part of my question) - "After this I have created credentials. Then edit > redirect_uri...". It is not working

Comment: Please check my edit your using the wrong type of credetinals.

Comment: I found another of your answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560850/httplistenerexception-access-is-denied-using-googlewebauthorizationbroker-auth/74286175#74286175 and have changed my code now.. as per Web applications (ASP.NET MVC) example in google oauth

Comment: but now its not sending me a token back..sharing my code in the question

Comment: Try reading though the [Web applications (ASP.NET Core 3)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3) sample.   Open a new question if you cant get it to work I have addressed the original question.